# force a transitive dependency version in golang

Tags: go, dependencies, go-modules

I have a question about dependencies in golang.
My application defines a go.mod like this:

```
module my.host.com/myapp

require (
    ext1.com/module1 v0.0.1
)

go 1.14
```

The dependency relationship is：

1. **ext1.com/module1 v0.0.1** depends on **ext3.com/module3 v0.0.3**

A security scan detects **ext3.com/module3 v0.0.3** is insecure and must be updated to **v0.0.4**.

Is there a way to "force" myapp to get only **module3 v0.0.4**, overriding the directives defined in **module1 v0.0.1** go.mod?

1. Let's say **ext1.com/module1 v0.0.1** is already at the latest version, so upgrading it doesn't work.

Would "replace" work?

```
module my.host.com/myapp

require (
    ext1.com/module1 v0.0.1
)

replace ext3.com/module3 v0.0.3 => ext3.com/module3 v0.0.4

go 1.14
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `go get -u ext3.com/module3@v0.0.4`.

This upgrades the module to **at least** the `v0.0.4`

Given the dependency `main -> B -> C`, when `main` requires a higher version of `C` than that required by `B`, the higher version is selected, with `// indirect`.

See this https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-require

> If the go directive specifies go 1.16 or lower, the go command adds an indirect requirement when the selected version of a module is higher than what is already implied (transitively) by the main module’s other dependencies. **That may occur because of an explicit upgrade** (go get -u ./...)

I quote this part because your go.mod has `go 1.14`